# Aptana IDE Shows "The Socket is EOF"

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I tried to connect SFTP connection in Aptana Studio
But it shows  "The Socket is EOF"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBURc.png)

Comment: Start with moving to Big Boys IDE like VSCode or one of the brilliant JetBrains tools :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the RSE (Remote System Explorer):

[Installing the Remote System Explorer](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.rse.doc.user/gettingstarted/g1installing.html)

Remote System Explorer is a perspective and toolkit that allows you to connect and work with a variety of remote systems. With the predefined plug-ins, you can look at remote file systems, transfer files between hosts, do remote search, execute commands and work with processes.